# Angular2 app is not loading in browser

Tags: javascript, angular

My `angular 2` application is not loading in google chrome. It takes forever to load & ultimately shows `Aw, Snap!` error.

Memory trace shows something going in infinite loop but no idea what might have gone wrong. I was changing my previous html files with new `flex-layout` equipped html files.

[image]

Anybody faced similar issue?
p.s. I'm working in latest of `angular2`, `material2`, `angular-cli`, `flex-layout`

Comment: check browser console to see if you are getting error or not

Comment: Browser console is not opening. But i'm also debugging from `webstorm debugger`, not getting any errors there.

Comment: perhaps your code has an infinite loop as you say? surely there's some code you've written - chances are, you've done something wrong

Comment: How did you setup angular2?

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: @HiteshKumar Project is too large to share.

Comment: @HarryMatharoo I set up project with `angular cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should answer the question if someone faces similar problem.

Issue was basically in the code I've written. It might be anything, but since console was not opening, I had to examine whole changed code.

In my case I had wrong variable in one of `dropdowns`. Instead of `Country list` I had `address type list` (copy-pasting is such a time waste)